# Mysql case when and order by issue

Tags: mysql

Have this query:

```
SELECT
  count(*) as Total, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN gender = 1 then 1 ELSE 0 END) Male, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN gender = 2 then 1 ELSE 0 END) Female, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN gender = 0 then 1 ELSE 0 END) Unknown, 
  CASE 
    WHEN age>2 AND age<15 THEN '2-15' 
    WHEN age>18 AND age<25 THEN '18-25' 
  END AS var
FROM
  persons 
WHERE
  1=1 
  AND `date` > '2012-01-10'
  AND `date` < '2013-01-07' 
GROUP BY 
  CASE 
    WHEN age>2 AND age<15 THEN '2-15' 
    WHEN age>18 AND age<25 THEN '18-25'
  END
```

And is resulting this:

```
Total Male  Female  Unknown var
29     17   12      0       NULL
7      0    7       0       18-25
3      0    3       0       2-15
```

**1st question:** 
Why is this resulting that NULL ? What could be done to only show results with values?

**2nd question:** 
mysql is ordering my `var` column with 18-25 before 2-15, migth be because of number 1 cames first then number 2. But the point is order that as numbers, and 2 came first then 18.

Cheers :)

Comment: Are your ages in interval 2 to 25 inclusive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1st answer**:
It is NULL because it does not satisfy any of your CASE conditions for the age. Adding a clause to the WHERE like this should do it:

```
WHERE (age > 2 AND age < 15) OR (age > 18 AND age < 25)
```

**2nd answer**:
You are correct, it is ordering them by strings (because that is what they are). Just change the direction of the sort by doing `ORDER ASC` or `ORDER DESC`

Comment: `( (age>=2 AND age<=15) OR (age>=11 AND age<=45) OR (age>=22 AND age<=44) )` Doenst show the last '22-44'. How can we fix that ?

Comment: @skdnewbie 22-44 falls completely within the range of 11-45, so it is most likely that those are getting classified as 11-45 before they are checked against the 22-44

Answer (score 2):

This is because all `CASE` expression has an (implied, default) `ELSE NULL` part. SO, any `age` value that is not caught by either the `age>2 AND age<15`or the `age>18 AND age<25` condition, results in the `NULL` value being grouped.

Solution is to add one more restriction at the `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE 1=1 
AND `date` > '2012-01-10' AND `date` < '2013-01-07' 
AND ( (age>2 AND age<15) OR (age>18 AND age<25) )        -- this
```

---

For the second question, you can use a function on `age` to avoid the comparison being made on the `var` (which is a string):

```
 ORDER BY MIN(age)
```

or just:

```
ORDER BY age
```

None of the above is by the SQL standard but it works in MySQL, under the default non-ANSI settings. If you want to be 100% by the book, you can change slightly the `var`:

```
SELECT count(*) as Total, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN gender = 1 then 1 ELSE 0 END) Male, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN gender = 2 then 1 ELSE 0 END) Female, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN gender = 0 then 1 ELSE 0 END) Unknown, 
  CASE 
    WHEN age>2 AND age<15 THEN '02-15'                    -- this was changed
    WHEN age>18 AND age<25 THEN '18-25' 
  END AS var
FROM persons 
WHERE 1=1 
  AND `date` > '2012-01-10' AND `date` < '2013-01-07' 
  AND ( (age>2 AND age<15) OR (age>18 AND age<25) )
GROUP BY 
  CASE 
     WHEN age>2 AND age<15 THEN '02-15' 
     WHEN age>18 AND age<25 THEN '18-25' 
  END
ORDER BY var ;
```

Answer (score 1):

you are getting `NULL`

because it doesnt meet your CASE

```
 CASE 
WHEN age>2 AND age<15 THEN '2-15'    // U HAVE BETWEEN 2-15
WHEN age>18 AND age<25 THEN '18-25'   // u have between 18-25

   // but u dont have between 15-18 
   //and u get null because your value is between 15-18
```

so try to add other case in that range.

second question because they are strings  , not numbers.

try order them by age